# Should you count rows or keep track of the number in another table?

Tags: database

Let's say you want to show the number of comments a certain submission has. You could count the rows in the comment table and find out the number that way using the associated submission id, or you could have an int column for the submission table, which increases/decreases in number when a comment is added/deleted to a certain submission.

Is the second option a viable option? Is it something you could/should do? If yes, when would it make sense to do it that way, for example to count the views of a submission?

Comment: You could add a counter column. But normally you only do that if it takes heavy DB performance to calculate it on-the-fly. Why make things complicated? Just calculate it in your select

Comment: The second option virtually never makes sense. You write too much code. Virtually the only time fields like that are calculated in practice is in a data warehouse.

Comment: I would count the rows. Int column could be problematic when you manually edited the database later. Or if multiple comments get submitted at the same time (exact same time is rare but still).

Comment: What's wrong with running a `select count(*)`?